# WiFi goes to sleep when device asleep

Tags: wi-fi, doze-mode

On my Samsung Galaxy S7, whenever the device goes to sleep, the Wifi goes to sleep as well.
Meaning:
* If I'm connected to a WiFi network and the device is idle for about 10 minutes (tested it), the device won't be connected to the WiFi network anymore (ping is unreachable)
* If entering a WiFi network area and device is idle, it won't connect to the network until I turn on the device manually.

*There are exceptions:*
* While charging
* When disabling `deviceidle` option via adb (`adb shell dumpsys deviceidle disable`), the problem is the option is reset after reboot

*What I've checked so far ?*
* Different Wifi networks
* All 'Keep WiFi on during sleep' options
* All 'Smart network switch' options
* Setting my router to specific channel and not auto
* Manually disabling almost all possible apps under 'doze' option
* An app to 'keep the device alive'

IMHO, as disabling 'deviceidle' actually fixes the issue (until next reboot), it's some kind of a bug in Android which tries to optimize the WiFi process, but, I hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: No 'WiFi saving' button, only 'test ping' and some diagnostics.  I'll try enabling the wifi scan and report back, thanks!

Comment: Actually I can't find the wifi scanning option neither

Comment: Android 7.0, found the WiFi scanning option, it was ON...

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: *Settings › WiFi › tap the "overflow menu button" on the top-right › Advanced › WiFi Standby* set to "always" should solve it.

Comment: Hi@Izzy, that's 'Keep WiFi on during sleep'  I referred to

Comment: See: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141444/android-phone-constantly-loses-wi-fi-connection/142340

Comment: Thank you @xavier_fakerat but it looks like most of the solution on the other page relates to the WiFi network itself while I encounter the issue on multiple networks.